# Linking Gitbox diff tool to FileMerge after upgrading to Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, filemerge, gitbox

I just upgraded to Xcode 5 and now Gitbox doesn't seem to be able to find FileMerge as the diff tool, and has no options for setting a path manually. Anyone know a way to link it up again?

Comment: In your question, it looks like the two paths are the same.  And when I launch my own copy of GitBox, it's working fine with the Filemerge embedded in Xcode 5.

Comment: Notice the "s" in "Contents", originally it was in "Content".

Comment: Errr, you're right, originally, it was "Contents". Hm, ok. Perhaps the difference is it changed from "Xcode.app" to "Xcode"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fail. Fail. Fail. The problem was I just needed to fire up Xcode apparently :)
Oops.

Comment: Same - after an OSX update (of Xcode), I needed to run Xcode once in order to apply the updates. All good after that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the active Xcode via Terminal:

```
   xcode-select --print-path
           Prints the path of the active Xcode folder
   or: xcode-select --switch <xcode_path>
           Sets the path for the active Xcode folder
   or: xcode-select --version
           Prints the version of xcode-select
```

And if that doesn't work, Xcode allows one to select which set of command line tools one can use (it's hidden in the "Locations" preference pane of Xcode.

Comment: I had this issue even with Xcode 8. I had a different name for Xcode, so changing the path with the above commands worked.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 8.3.3 I went to preferences and under the tab Locations choose the CommandLineTools dropdown which was empty, and applied Xcode 8.3.3

Now my Gitbox opens FileMerge when comparing files, like it used to.

Answer (score 2):

That happened precisely because your Xcode is still referencing the old version. Open `Xcode > Go to preferences > Then click on "Locations" Tab`. You will see a dropdown labeled "Command Line Tools". Pick your latest version and voila!